# How to hide UILabel Swift: Label is creating space in table view controller when Label is set to hidden

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel

I am trying to hide a `UILabel`..!

I have taken a table view controller in storyboard which contains `UIlabel`,`TableView` & `Segmented Control`.

I have two categories one is Data & Empty data.

When user clicks on Data -> data should appear in TableView & Label should hide.

When user clicks on Empty -> data should hide & label should appear.

I could do that... But Label is doing a problem here (It is creating a gap)

**Problem:**

Label is creating a gap on top of table view when there is data.

**Question:**

1. How to remove label when it is hidden.
2. I want to display the label at the center of the view(user friendly).

**ScreenShots:**
[image: Stoaryboard]

[image: StoaryBoard 1]

**Simulator:**
[image]
[image]

Code:

```
// MARK: - Properties
    let sectionHeaders = ["One","Two"];
    var rowValues = [["First","Second","Three"],["four","five","six"]];

    // MARK: - IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet weak var noDataLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = "Table View"
        noDataLabel.isHidden = true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        if (rowValues.isEmpty) {
            return 0
        } else {
            return sectionHeaders.count
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if (rowValues.isEmpty) {
            return 0
        } else {
            return rowValues[section].count
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sectionHeaders[section]
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = rowValues[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];

        return cell
    }

    // MARK: - IBActions

    @IBAction func segmentButtonPressed(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            if rowValues.isEmpty {
                noDataLabel.isHidden = true
                rowValues = [["First","Second","Three"],["four","five","six"]];
            }
        } else {
            rowValues.removeAll()
            noDataLabel.isHidden = false
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Comment: @Md.MuzahidulIslam No, Im not using auto Layout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the `UILabel` frame height as shown below that will solve your problem.

```
func editLabelHeight(edit: Bool) {
        if edit {
            var labelFrame = noDataLabel.frame
            labelFrame.size.height = 0
            noDataLabel.frame = labelFrame
        }
        else {
            var labelFrame = noDataLabel.frame
            labelFrame.size.height = 44
            noDataLabel.frame = labelFrame
        }
    }
```

In your `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        editLabelHeight(edit: true)
    }
```

In `IBAction`

```
@IBAction func segmentButtonPressed(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            if rowValues.isEmpty {
                noDataLabel.isHidden = true
                editLabelHeight(edit: true)
                rowValues = [["First","Second","Three"],["four","five","six"]]
            }
        } else {
            rowValues.removeAll()
            editLabelHeight(edit: false)
            noDataLabel.isHidden = false
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```